# No definition for classes from another package

Tags: r, r-s4

I hit a weird problem in a large codebase and cannot really figure out where to start debugging. Long story short, there is third party package, we'll call `foo` with `DESCRIPTION`

```r
Package: foo
Type: Package
Title: Foo
Version: 0.1.0
Author: Foo Dev
Maintainer: Foo Dev <foo@foo>
Description: Does foo
License: MIT
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 7.1.2
```

`NAMESPACE`

```r
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

exportClasses(FooA)
exportClasses(FooB)
```

and code

```r
#' @export
setClass("FooA", representation())

#' @export
setClass("FooB", representation())
```

I use this package in another package, let's call it `bar`,

```r
Package: bar
Type: Package
Title: Bar
Version: 0.1.0
Author: Bar Dev
Maintainer: Bar Dev <bar@bar>
Description: Does bar
License: BSD
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 7.1.2
Imports:
  foo
```

where I define following generics

```r
#' @name bar
#' @rdname bar
setGeneric(
  "bar",
  function(fooa, foob) { standardGeneric("bar") })


#' bar
#'
#' @param fooa FooA
#' @param foob FooB
#' @name bar
#' @rdname bar
#' @aliases bar,FooA,FooB-method
#' @export
setMethod(
  "bar",
  signature(fooa = "FooA", foob = "FooB"),
  function(fooa, foob) {

  }
)
```

I check the package and boom, I get:

```r
Found the following significant warnings:
  Warning: in method for ‘bar’ with signature ‘fooa="FooA",foob="FooB"’: no definition for classes “FooA”, “FooB”
```

If I change `signature` to for example

```r
  signature(fooa = "FooA", foob = "ANY"),
```

or

```r
  signature(fooa = "ANY", foob = "FooB"),
```

things run smoothly. I can also define all kinds of generics, as long as they dispatch on only one of these classes at the time.

I use `R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)`, if that's relevant here.

What is going on here?

Comment: Read [this](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/namespace.html) and more specifically you probably need `#' @exportClass D` where `D` is your class.. In `{foo}`. But please read the link. Also, remember to run `devtools::document()` before building `{foo}`.

Comment: Thanks @Mossa. So `@importClassesFrom` does the trick. However, I still don't understand why I can use each of this classes separately in my project. but not in the same signature :/

Comment: Glad to be able to help; I don't get the problem exactly, but others may, so please update the main question.

Comment: I'll be happy to accept this as answer @Mossa, and investigate further on my own. I am just curious what's the catch here, because this behavior is incredibly counter-intuitive. If it just failed, right away, it would be clear that classes are not in the scope.